# At which points the limit of the following function exists?

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to determine that at which points the following function has limit.

> $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if} \;x \in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q \\\\\frac{1}{n}&\text{if}\;x=\frac{m}{n} \in \Bbb Q\;\text{where}\;\gcd(m,n)=1\end{cases}$$

Any suggestion is appreciated?

Comment: See [Thomae's function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Very similar to Thomae's function(only difference is their domain is $[0,1]$ and value of the function at zero is $1$). Is continuous(and hence limit exists) at $0$ and all other irrational numbers. Showing continuity at $0$ is very simple(for $x\in \mathbb{Q}^c$ $|f(x)|=0<\epsilon$, and for $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ you can find N s.t. $n>N\Rightarrow \frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$ by archimedian).
2. For disproving continuity at $\mathbb{Q}$ use the sequence definition for continuity, i.e. $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$ is true iff for every converging sequence $x_n\rightarrow a$, $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(a)$. But for rational numbers, you could come up with a converging sequence of irrational numbers around $a$ and $\{f(x_n)\}=0,0,0,...$ i.e. does not converge to non zero $f(a)=\frac{1}{n},a=\frac{m}{n},gcd(m,n)=1$
3. For continuity at irrational points, use the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition, need to prove $|f(x)|<\epsilon\ with\ |x-a|<\delta$ if $x\in \mathbb{Q}^c$, clearly $0<\epsilon$, for $x\in \mathbb{Q}$, we will have only finitely many rational numbers in the interval $(a-1,a+1)$ s.t. $\frac{1}{n}\geq\epsilon$, so just take $\delta=min\{1,\frac{1}{n+1} (s.t.\ \frac{1}{n}\geq\epsilon)$} and hence $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$

eg. take $a=\sqrt{2}$ and $\epsilon=\frac{1}{8}$, then $n (s.t.\ \frac{1}{n}\geq \frac{1}{8})=${1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}

The reason why we can do this is this, you can find an N s.t. $N\geq\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ and take the infimum(exists because bounded below by $\epsilon$) of the set of such N's, let that be N', then clearly there are only finitely many N's before N'